# pass multiple value parameter to api jquery

Tags: jquery, api, parameters

I'm trying to pass values from a form to an api.I can connect to the api and pass some values, but I'm having trouble with a parameter that has multiple values.For example, I want to pass weight. I can do that by `data.Weight = $("#pkWeight").val();`. I also want to pass the parameter `Observation`. This parameter has multiple parts (excuse my lack of knowledge to use the correct terms). It is setup as follows:

```
<Observation>
<ObsItem Time=$double Conc=$double>
</Observation>
```

I'm getting the `Time` and `Conc` values from my form, but not sure how to format them to pass into the api.I'm thinking I need to put the values in an array, but I'm not sure how to get there.Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered using JSON?

Answer (score 2):

please use below code , i hope it will work fine.

```js
  $.ajax({
        url: DomainUrl,//pass your url
        type: "GET",
        contenttype: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",--this for return data type
        data: { "Weight":   $("#pkWeight").val() ,
        "Observation":$("#Observation").val() 
        },
        success: function (data) {
         // your logic goes here
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log(data.error);
        }
    });
    
    your server side code should be like
    public class DataTransferObject
    {
        public string Weight { get; set; }
        public string Observation { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

How about an $.ajax request with $callback=? on the querystring:

```
$(".button").click(function () {

    var apiURL="https://api.com";

    $.ajax({
        url: apiURL+"&callback=?",
        data: {weight: data.Weight, observation: data.Observation}",
        type: 'POST',
        success: function (resp) {
            alert(resp);
        },
        error: function(e) {
            alert('Error: '+e);
        }  
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create an object and add all fields that you want to send the server

```
var finalData = {};
finalData.name = 'ABC';
finalData.age = '25';
finalData.city = 'XYZ';
$.ajax({
url: apiURL+"&callback=?",
data: {data: finalData},
type: 'POST',
success: function (resp) {
 // do your stuff
})
```